# I got Xampp but now what do I do to start coding in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp

My goal is link a relational database to my React Native project but for now, I just want to create tables and insert some some dummy data into those tables just to get things working.

I've downloaded Xampp, turned on Apache and MySQL so what do I do next?  Which IDE is the best one to code in SQL?

I've read online somewhere that I have to hit admin button of MySQL module, click Databases tab, type a name, click create

But can't find admin button of MySQL

How do I go about making this work?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question, it's about how to get started with SQL/xampp. You should find & run through some tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the default option, just go ahead and type http://localhost/ in your browser (with apache and mySql on).

And then if it works, it should show something like this:

[image]
If you see that, everything is set and done, and you are ready to go, navigate to http://localhost/phpmyadmin

[image]

In the left you have "New" button (mine is in spanish, sorry).
There you can create a DB. It asks for a table, the name and how many fields.

[image]

It asks for the fields, the types.

[image]

And you can start toying around.

Hope it helps!

---

**Edit:**
The real issue here, was the hosts file didn't have the definition of localhost.

*In windows:*
Go to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` open hosts file and add `127.0.0.1       localhost`.

*In mac:*
To find the hosts file, open Finder and, in Finder’s menu bar, select Go > Go to Folder. In the box, type the following location and press Return. `/private/etc/hosts` edit the file, and add `127.0.0.1       localhost`

Comment: Ah, I see!  But when I type http://localhost/ in my broswer, I get the "this site can't be reached" page.  Both apache and MySQL are on.

Comment: Did you type precisely as I stated? http:// localhost/ ?

Comment: Yeah, it didn't work.

Comment: Did you just installed xampp by default and didn't change the port?

Comment: Yeah, I just installed xampp.  I never set up any ports or anything like that.

Comment: Oh! I know precisely what's happening, go to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc in your explorer, and find hosts file, you need to add "127.0.0.1       localhost"

Comment: Ok, I just turned on port 8080 so I typed  http://localhost/8080 and I still get that "this site can't be reached" page to come up

Comment: If you set a port you access it by localhost:8080 not /

Comment: My bad, didnt ask, solution right away, give me a sec